# How to find super class from MemberScope reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I have a few reflection methods i'm using:

```
  def typeMirror = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
  def instanceMirror = typeMirror.reflect(this)
  def members = instanceMirror.symbol.typeSignature.members
```

From members i'm trying to do something like this (I understand this is not correct, but i've tried various ways without success):

```
  def modelMembers = members.filter(member => member.typeSignature == Model)
```

Where Model is the super class. The problem is I can only seem to figure out the sub classing typeSignature. How can i filter the members based on if they're a subclass of Model?

Comment: nah doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very handy `<:<` operator to test if a type is a subtype of another:

```
def modelMembers = members.filter(_.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Model])
```

*Note*: this will only get you fields, not methods with `Model` return type.

Example:

```
trait A
class B extends A
class C extends A

class X {
  val hello: C = null
  var world: B = null
}
```

---

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[X].members.filter(_.typeSignature <:< typeOf[A])
res0: Iterable[Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(variable world, value hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

it does seem to work for me?

```
package load.data

abstract class AbstractPoint
case class Point() extends AbstractPoint

object ModelTest {
  def main(arg: Array[String]) =
    {
      val li = List(new Point())
      assert(li.filter(_.isInstanceOf[AbstractPoint]).length == 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this works. The problem i'm having is related to reflection. I'm not sure how to tell if the Symbol object is my base class or not.

Comment: Did you try with the reflection code? Obviously your example here will work, but this is not what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the approach should be involving reflections? My implication was that for your specific problem reflections aren't necesarily required or did I get you wrong?

Comment: def members = instanceMirror.symbol.typeSignature.members returns a MemberScope which has a list of type Symbol i can't seem to figure out how to relate that Symbol and figure out if it's my base class of Model or not.

Answer (score 0):

Found a little bit of a hack. If anyone knows a more concrete way I would love to see it.

```
  def modelMembers = {
    val filtered = members.filter(member => member.typeSignature.baseClasses.size > 0 && member.isTerm && !member.isMethod)
    filtered.filter(_.typeSignature.baseClasses.exists(_.name.toString == "Model"))
  }
```